# Angular 5 submit not firing

Tags: angular, typescript, mean-stack

I'm currently learning Angular and I'm following some tutorials, I've created a simple register component:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {



  form: FormGroup;

  createForm() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: '',
      username: '',
      password: '',
      confirm: ''
    })
  }

  onRegisterSubmit() {
    console.log('this.form');
  }

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { 
    this.createForm();
  }  

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

and have the following form defined in the html:

```html
<h1 class="page-header">Registration Page</h1>

<form [formGroup]="form" ng-submit="onRegisterSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="*Username" formControlName="username" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">E-mail</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="*Email" formControlName="email" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="password" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="*Password" formControlName="password" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="confirm">Confirm Password</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="confirm" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="*Confirm Password" formControlName="confirm" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit" />
</form>
```

I don't seem to be able to get the `onRegisterSubmit` function to fire.

I have tried to use different events against the form (`(submit)`, `(ng-submit)`, `ng-submit`) and to debug the form but I can't see any events firing when I click submit.

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `(ngSubmit)="onRegisterSubmit()"`

Answer (score 4):

To achieve expected result, use **ngSubmit**

As per angular documentation - ngSubmit
"You can listen to the directive's ngSubmit event to be notified when the user has triggered a form submission. The ngSubmit event will be emitted with the original form submission event."

Check this link for more details - https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm